# Project a 2D Point to 3D using a depth value. Maya Python API

Tags: python, api, matrix, projection, maya

I'm trying to figure out how to project a 3D point from a 2D Point. I'd like to be able to give it a depth value to project to. Anyone have any examples for maya?

Thanks!

Here's the best I've been able to do:

```
def screenToWorld(point2D=None,
                  depth=None,
                  viewMatrix=None,
                  projectionMatrix=None,
                  width=None,
                  height=None):
    '''
    @param point2D - 2D Point.
    @param viewMatrix - MMatrix of modelViewMatrix (World inverse of camera.)
    @param projectionMatrix - MMatrix of camera's projectionMatrix.
    @param width - Resolution width of camera.
    @param height - Resolution height of camera.
    Returns worldspace MPoint.
    '''
    point3D = OpenMaya.MPoint()
    point3D.x = (2.0 * (point2D[0] / width)) - 1.0
    point3D.y = (2.0 * (point2D[1] / height)) - 1.0

    viewProjectionMatrix = (viewMatrix * projectionMatrix)

    point3D.z = viewProjectionMatrix(3, 2)
    point3D.w = viewProjectionMatrix(3, 3)
    point3D.x = point3D.x * point3D.w
    point3D.y = point3D.y * point3D.w
    point3D = point3D * viewProjectionMatrix.inverse()

    return point3D
```

As you can tell it does not use the depth value. I'm not sure how to incorporate it using the projection matrix and viewMatrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
-Chris

Comment: Have you tried this with Z in worldspace units and W =1?   Muliply that by the inverse of the matrix and divide the result by W and see if that's what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think i got a solution for this:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya

def projectPoint(worldPnt, camPnt, depth):
    '''
    @param worldPnt - MPoint of point to project. (WorldSpace)
    @param camPnt - MPoint of camera position. (WorldSpace)
    @param depth - Float value of distance.
    Returns list of 3 floats.
    '''
    #Get vector from camera to point and normalize it.
    mVec_pointVec = worldPnt - camPnt
    mVec_pointVec.normalize()

    #Multiply it by the depth and the camera offset to it.
    mVec_pointVec *= depth
    mVec_pointVec += OpenMaya.MVector(camPnt.x, camPnt.y, camPnt.z)

    return [mVec_pointVec.x, mVec_pointVec.y, mVec_pointVec.z]
```

I didn't really need to convert it to 2d then back to 3d. I just needed to extend the vector from camera.

Comment: what if the camera is orthographic, or has a film offset?

Comment: I don't think it would work in an orthographic camera, but film offset would work.